# Is there any time when it is better to slice the same list twice?

Tags: python, list, slice

Here's the situation:  I have a simple list

```
my_list = list(range(10))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I can perform two slices on it and print the results like this:

```
print(my_list[9:1:-1][::-1]) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But this can of course be done with a single slice:

```
print(my_list[2:]) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there ever a good reason to do what I've shown in the second line of code, i.e. slice twice the same list?  It seems very unpythonic but perhaps there is a use case where the slicing parameters are fed by variables. Why does the functionality exist to double slice the same list as I've done above?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call reversing the list slicing it. Even if you did want to call it that, yes there are absolutely times when this would be useful. Perhaps you first want to access a certain range within the list, then reverse it. That's perfectly valid.

Comment: Why would the functionality for slicing a list twice **not** exist? The first slice results in a second list which you can slice (and do anything else, for that matter) just like you could the first one.

Comment: "Why does the functionality exist to double slice the same list as I've done above?" This question doesn't really make sense .. this is just a consequence of the language syntax..  `my_list[9:1:-1]` is a valid expression, therefore, it evaluates to some object, and you can slice the result of a valid expression (sometimes this would require parentheses)

Comment: I feel like this question is conceptually similar to asking "why should I prefer `x = 1 + 1 + 1` over `x = 3`?"  Obviously if you remove all context, it appears that one option is always superior to the other, but clearly there must also exist situations where the context matters and the expression cannot be simplified.

Comment: So far, we have one Answer, 'can't think of a good reason' and several comments, of course there is a reason for it.  But so far, no one has given me a use case where you couldn't do a double slice with a single slice.  And yes, my second slice is just a reversal, but it is still a slice.  So, when would you slice twice instead of once? @0x5453

Comment: @h0r53  Can you give me an example of when you could not slice once and you needed to slice the same list twice?  That is my question.  When would it be better to slice twice instead of once?  Just one example please.

Comment: @higram - The most simple example is a multi-dimensional array, which uses the same concept. Otherwise, maybe you just want to be pedantic about slicing an array. Maybe in practice you are working on something like a large byte array. Clearly you could do the accesses in multiple single slices, but doing so could become cumbersome. In a real world application it would come down to preference.

Comment: @h0r53, but does it ever make sense to do it on a list? And if so, when?

Comment: @higrm, see the edit on my answer for a semi-plausible example.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a "good reason" to slice twice, but want to push back on "Why does the functionality exist to double slice the same list ...?". Because you're *not* slicing the same list twice. The initial `my_list[9:1:-1]` creates a brand new list, and then `[::-1]` slices *that* list. The language did nothing at all to cater to that: `[::-1]` applies to any sliceable object, and `my_list[9:1:-1]` is just one of many ways to create a sliceable object.

So your question is akin to asking "Why does the functionality exist to add twice to the same integer?" about the code `i = j + 5 + 8`. ;-)

### An example

This is somewhat contrived, but if it came up in real life in a non-time-critical section, I wouldn't hesitate to use a double slice.

Suppose you want to get every 98'th element in a sequence, but also in reverse order. So, e.g.,

```
>>> xs = list(range(1000))
>>> xs[::98][::-1]
[980, 882, 784, 686, 588, 490, 392, 294, 196, 98, 0]
```

That *can* be gotten with a single slice, but I bet most people would struggle a bit to get the spelling right:

```
>>> xs[980::-98]
[980, 882, 784, 686, 588, 490, 392, 294, 196, 98, 0]
>>>
```

Note that you have to compute the 980 yourself, else you won't know where the reversed slice should start. And you *must* omit the second slice argument (or explicitly say `None` there).

`0` doesn't work, because a slice stops before reaching the second index:

```
>>> xs[980:0:-98]
[980, 882, 784, 686, 588, 490, 392, 294, 196, 98]
```

Note that the trailing `0` is missing then.  And -1 doesn't work either, despite that

```
>>> list(range(980, -1, -98))
[980, 882, 784, 686, 588, 490, 392, 294, 196, 98, 0]
```

works fine. But that's `range()`. In the context of *slicing*, `-1` is taken to mean "the last element of the sequence", not the first.

```
>>> xs[980:-1:-98]
[]
```

Going backwards from element 980 to element 999 gives, of course, an empty list.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I knew it was making a copy, I just didn't realize the second slicing brackets right after the first slice was something that would/should work.  Sometimes the syntax confuses me.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like a plausible use case for a double slice.  Afterwards, I was thinking that there could be a case where you need some odd combination of the list, that isn't some 'factorable' step function.  Like you want every fourth and fifth element.

Comment: But in the 4th-and-5th case, double slicing wouldn't help you either. A slice has a constant interval between selections, and that property holds no matter how often you chain slices. 4th-and-5th is most easily done not by slicing at all, but by, e.g., `itertools.compress(the_sequence, itertools.cycle([0,0,0,1,1]))`

Answer (score 2):

Getting reverse slices right in the general case is surprisingly tricky.

I previously have had the problem where I wanted to get a reversed slice from a list where the endpoints depended on user input. So, a toy example:

```
start = int(input('low index for slice (inclusive): '))
end = int(input('high index for slice (inclusive): '))
my_slice = original[end:start-1:-1]
```

Oops: when `0` is provided for `start`, the index becomes `-1`, which causes it not to work as intended. We could special-case that situation and replace `-1` with `None`; but "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", and "simple is better than complex". Much nicer to just write `original[start:end+1][::-1]`, which is also easier to understand.

Comment: Nice example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this -

```
print(my_list[9:1:-1][::-1]) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then you are first creating new list which is my_list[9:1:-1] and then you are slicing that new list by creating another new list my_list[9:1:-1][::-1]
So this will take more space.

But when you do this -

```
print(my_list[2:]) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You are creating a new list only once, which takes less space

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  My question is whether there is ever a time when you want to take up more space and slice the same list twice.  I am just asking to see a use case for that.